# Removing images with Greasemonkey?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I would like to stop images from loading, as in not even get a chance to download, using greasemonkey.  Right now I have

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

for (var i=0; i<images.length; i++){
    images[i].src = "";
}
```

but I don't think this actually stops the images from downloading.  Anyone know how to stop the images from loading?

Thanks for your time and help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost all images are not downloaded. So your script almost working as is.

I've tested the following script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           stop downloading images
// @namespace      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387388
// @include        http://flickr.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var n = images.length; n--> 0;) {
  var img = images[n];
  img.setAttribute("src", "");
}
```

Use a dedicated extension to manage images (something like [ImgLikeOpera](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1672)).

If you'd like to filter images on all browser then a proxy with filtering capabilities might help e.g., [Privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org/).

Comment: I've just tried this and images are still loading in FF9 ... they hide some time later, seems that GM can't interrupt loading images via the DOM

Answer (score 3):

If you want to disable images downloading for all websites (which I guess you might not be doing) and are using firefox, why not just disable them in preferences? Go to the content tab and switch off "Load images automatically".

Answer (score 1):

I believe greasemonkey script are executed after the loading of the page, so I guess the images are loaded too.

Comment: Greasemonkey scripts are actually initiated on the DOMContentLoaded event meaning that images will not necessarily be loaded. Source: http://wiki.greasespot.net/DOMContentLoaded

Comment: In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.(c) Zen of Python -- most of images are not loaded (at least in my setup and from the link posted by @JimmyP follows it is a common case).

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not greasemonkey, but you could try the "IMG Like Opera" extension.  It definitely keeps the files from downloading, and has more flexibility than just on/off.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely related, but I use this bit of code to toggle displaying of images in Firefox in the EasyGestures plugin.  I am not sure if this can be translated to greasemonkey, but it might be a starting point.

```
var prefs = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"].
            getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefBranch);
var nImgPref = prefs.getIntPref("permissions.default.image");
if (nImgPref == 1) {
  prefs.setIntPref("permissions.default.image",2)
  alert('Images off.');
} else {
  prefs.setIntPref("permissions.default.image",1)
  alert('Images on.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you know that the images still load? Maybe you should assert it using Firebug or some such?